# Ошибка DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: java, android

Что это за ошибка ребят?

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
> >     0xffff]: 65536

Comment: Частично проблема решена

Comment: Вам надо multidex родключить

Comment: Я просто спустил версию плай сарвиса .незнаю насколько это правильное решение но получилось

Comment: В старых версиях меньше кода и в итоге проект вошёл в лимит 65К методов. Если вы подключите ещё к-л либу и/или повысите версию сервисов у вас опять будет выкидывать эту ошибку. Решить же проблему правильно - это добавить 2-4 строки в проект